# Relay Fix at Normally Open

Tags: radio-control

I am using my RF module to send a High signal to relay but just once by a push button.As soon as I release it the Relay goes to NC . How can I Fix it to stay at NO . I thought of using a Flip-Flop.

Comment: What is your desired behavior? You want to send one pulse and have it stay on... until what? Forever? Power is removed? Another pulse? Generally what you're describing is referred to as a latch, but without a specific description of the desired behavior it's not possible to give you an exact answer.

Comment: Sir I will send pulse once to move relay at NO and send another pulse to move it to NC.like using a remote for a car.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is a very good way to go...

you can use a t flip flop so you the q output can hold the relay in the state you need and can toogle every time you press the button..

here the T flip flip, your signal every time you press the button must be connected to the clock

[image]

and the output signal diagram looks like

[image]

## Edit

you can replace the flip flop with its equivalent nand gates

[image]

or even more, considering that every nand gate can be schematizied with diodes
like

but as you can see you will need more more elements and more place on the main board if you really want to replace the flipflop

[image]

Comment: Can there be any other method than using Flip Flops